# HTML - can images be displayed without hosting online?

Tags: html, image

**The problem**

I have recently started learning basic HTML.

From  [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

When I came to the part of displaying images, it was given that a URL had to be given.

I googled around and on some forums, I found that hosting online is not necessary as far as we are viewing it on a locally(That is on the same machine that the code is being written). we can use the following syntax:

```
<img src = "file:\\C:\Documents and Settings\example.jpg">
```

**WHAT I WANNA DO**

I want to write a simple HTML document and distribute it to friends and family. ie i will be mailing the file to them or posting it in the public folder on dropbox. For this I want to include my photo in the document.

**the question**

1. Is hosting the image online absolutely necessary?
2. Is there any way to bundle the image along with the HTML file without having to host the image online?(I don't mind if the size of the file increases)
3. If hosting must be done then please suggest a website where images can be hosted easily and the upload speed is decent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questioner is actually asking how to EMBED an image into the HTML file itself. If an image is embedded, there is no need to host it elsewhere. As such the best approach for this use case is as follows -

1. Convert the image by encoding to base64.
2. Add the base64 encoded image data in the HTML file.

Example:

```html
<html><body><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t+KAAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAKT2lDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAHjanVNnVFPpFj333vRCS4iAlEtvUhUIIFJCi4AUkSYqIQkQSoghodkVUcERRUUEG8igiAOOjoCMFVEsDIoK2AfkIaKOg6OIisr74Xuja9a89+bN/rXXPues852zzwfACAyWSDNRNYAMqUIeEeCDx8TG4eQuQIEKJHAAEAizZCFz/SMBAPh+PDwrIsAHvgABeNMLCADATZvAMByH/w/qQplcAYCEAcB0kThLCIAUAEB6jkKmAEBGAYCdmCZTAKAEAGDLY2LjAFAtAGAnf+bTAICd+Jl7AQBblCEVAaCRACATZYhEAGg7AKzPVopFAFgwABRmS8Q5ANgtADBJV2ZIALC3AMDOEAuyAAgMADBRiIUpAAR7AGDIIyN4AISZABRG8lc88SuuEOcqAAB4mbI8uSQ5RYFbCC1xB1dXLh4ozkkXKxQ2YQJhmkAuwnmZGTKBNA/g88wAAKCRFRHgg/P9eM4Ors7ONo62Dl8t6r8G/yJiYuP+5c+rcEAAAOF0ftH+LC+zGoA7BoBt/qIl7gRoXgugdfeLZrIPQLUAoOnaV/Nw+H48PEWhkLnZ2eXk5NhKxEJbYcpXff5nwl/AV/1s+X48/Pf14L7iJIEyXYFHBPjgwsz0TKUcz5IJhGLc5o9H/LcL//wd0yLESWK5WCoU41EScY5EmozzMqUiiUKSKcUl0v9k4t8s+wM+3zUAsGo+AXuRLahdYwP2SycQWHTA4vcAAPK7b8HUKAgDgGiD4c93/+8//UegJQCAZkmScQAAXkQkLlTKsz/HCAAARKCBKrBBG/TBGCzABhzBBdzBC/xgNoRCJMTCQhBCCmSAHHJgKayCQiiGzbAdKmAv1EAdNMBRaIaTcA4uwlW4Dj1wD/phCJ7BKLyBCQRByAgTYSHaiAFiilgjjggXmYX4IcFIBBKLJCDJiBRRIkuRNUgxUopUIFVIHfI9cgI5h1xGupE7yAAygvyGvEcxlIGyUT3UDLVDuag3GoRGogvQZHQxmo8WoJvQcrQaPYw2oefQq2gP2o8+Q8cwwOgYBzPEbDAuxsNCsTgsCZNjy7EirAyrxhqwVqwDu4n1Y8+xdwQSgUXACTYEd0IgYR5BSFhMWE7YSKggHCQ0EdoJNwkDhFHCJyKTqEu0JroR+cQYYjIxh1hILCPWEo8TLxB7iEPENyQSiUMyJ7mQAkmxpFTSEtJG0m5SI+ksqZs0SBojk8naZGuyBzmULCAryIXkneTD5DPkG+Qh8lsKnWJAcaT4U+IoUspqShnlEOU05QZlmDJBVaOaUt2ooVQRNY9aQq2htlKvUYeoEzR1mjnNgxZJS6WtopXTGmgXaPdpr+h0uhHdlR5Ol9BX0svpR+iX6AP0dwwNhhWDx4hnKBmbGAcYZxl3GK+YTKYZ04sZx1QwNzHrmOeZD5lvVVgqtip8FZHKCpVKlSaVGyovVKmqpqreqgtV81XLVI+pXlN9rkZVM1PjqQnUlqtVqp1Q61MbU2epO6iHqmeob1Q/pH5Z/YkGWcNMw09DpFGgsV/jvMYgC2MZs3gsIWsNq4Z1gTXEJrHN2Xx2KruY/R27iz2qqaE5QzNKM1ezUvOUZj8H45hx+Jx0TgnnKKeX836K3hTvKeIpG6Y0TLkxZVxrqpaXllirSKtRq0frvTau7aedpr1Fu1n7gQ5Bx0onXCdHZ4/OBZ3nU9lT3acKpxZNPTr1ri6qa6UbobtEd79up+6Ynr5egJ5Mb6feeb3n+hx9L/1U/W36p/VHDFgGswwkBtsMzhg8xTVxbzwdL8fb8VFDXcNAQ6VhlWGX4YSRudE8o9VGjUYPjGnGXOMk423GbcajJgYmISZLTepN7ppSTbmmKaY7TDtMx83MzaLN1pk1mz0x1zLnm+eb15vft2BaeFostqi2uGVJsuRaplnutrxuhVo5WaVYVVpds0atna0l1rutu6cRp7lOk06rntZnw7Dxtsm2qbcZsOXYBtuutm22fWFnYhdnt8Wuw+6TvZN9un2N/T0HDYfZDqsdWh1+c7RyFDpWOt6azpzuP33F9JbpL2dYzxDP2DPjthPLKcRpnVOb00dnF2e5c4PziIuJS4LLLpc+Lpsbxt3IveRKdPVxXeF60vWdm7Obwu2o26/uNu5p7ofcn8w0nymeWTNz0MPIQ+BR5dE/C5+VMGvfrH5PQ0+BZ7XnIy9jL5FXrdewt6V3qvdh7xc+9j5yn+M+4zw33jLeWV/MN8C3yLfLT8Nvnl+F30N/I/9k/3r/0QCngCUBZwOJgUGBWwL7+Hp8Ib+OPzrbZfay2e1BjKC5QRVBj4KtguXBrSFoyOyQrSH355jOkc5pDoVQfujW0Adh5mGLw34MJ4WHhVeGP45wiFga0TGXNXfR3ENz30T6RJZE3ptnMU85ry1KNSo+qi5qPNo3ujS6P8YuZlnM1VidWElsSxw5LiquNm5svt/87fOH4p3iC+N7F5gvyF1weaHOwvSFpxapLhIsOpZATIhOOJTwQRAqqBaMJfITdyWOCnnCHcJnIi/RNtGI2ENcKh5O8kgqTXqS7JG8NXkkxTOlLOW5hCepkLxMDUzdmzqeFpp2IG0yPTq9MYOSkZBxQqohTZO2Z+pn5mZ2y6xlhbL+xW6Lty8elQfJa7OQrAVZLQq2QqboVFoo1yoHsmdlV2a/zYnKOZarnivN7cyzytuQN5zvn//tEsIS4ZK2pYZLVy0dWOa9rGo5sjxxedsK4xUFK4ZWBqw8uIq2Km3VT6vtV5eufr0mek1rgV7ByoLBtQFr6wtVCuWFfevc1+1dT1gvWd+1YfqGnRs+FYmKrhTbF5cVf9go3HjlG4dvyr+Z3JS0qavEuWTPZtJm6ebeLZ5bDpaql+aXDm4N2dq0Dd9WtO319kXbL5fNKNu7g7ZDuaO/PLi8ZafJzs07P1SkVPRU+lQ27tLdtWHX+G7R7ht7vPY07NXbW7z3/T7JvttVAVVN1WbVZftJ+7P3P66Jqun4lvttXa1ObXHtxwPSA/0HIw6217nU1R3SPVRSj9Yr60cOxx++/p3vdy0NNg1VjZzG4iNwRHnk6fcJ3/ceDTradox7rOEH0x92HWcdL2pCmvKaRptTmvtbYlu6T8w+0dbq3nr8R9sfD5w0PFl5SvNUyWna6YLTk2fyz4ydlZ19fi753GDborZ752PO32oPb++6EHTh0kX/i+c7vDvOXPK4dPKy2+UTV7hXmq86X23qdOo8/pPTT8e7nLuarrlca7nuer21e2b36RueN87d9L158Rb/1tWeOT3dvfN6b/fF9/XfFt1+cif9zsu72Xcn7q28T7xf9EDtQdlD3YfVP1v+3Njv3H9qwHeg89HcR/cGhYPP/pH1jw9DBY+Zj8uGDYbrnjg+OTniP3L96fynQ89kzyaeF/6i/suuFxYvfvjV69fO0ZjRoZfyl5O/bXyl/erA6xmv28bCxh6+yXgzMV70VvvtwXfcdx3vo98PT+R8IH8o/2j5sfVT0Kf7kxmTk/8EA5jz/GMzLdsAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiUAAICDAAD5/wAAgOkAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdvkl/FRgAAQ35JREFUeNrs3XecHXW9//HX6btne8tuNpVAAiQEQoRQAqEGkCoqqJQfoGCBq2L3iooXBQtX9KIXFbAiiIBKES5ITwMSCOmE9L6b3Ww9u3v29N8fM2AgbcspU97Px+M8kpBkyX5m5vue78y3eKY+tBkRsYwqoB4YAdQAlXv5lALlQAgIm78OmL/n2e1rFQNF7/v6/UB0t19ngE4gAfQAfUAM6DZ/3bmXTxvQCjQDHTpkItbgVwlE8qIIGAOMNn8ca/58NNBgfuqAYB7+He8P+ephfL34buHeDGwzP1uArebPt5o3EiKiQBexhTJgInDIbp8J5o+jHPo9B83v7UDf33ZgvflZt9tnLRDRqSOiQBcphHLgcGAKMNn88XBgnEqzT++E/qy9/N4WYBWwEngLWGH+2K2yiSjQRbJlBDAdmAYcbf44kfe+q5bhGWt+ztntv2XM3vsS4E3zx8VAi8olsnceDYoTeVeJGd7HAScAMzDecYt1bAMWAq8Ar5kh36uyiKiHLu42EjgFONkM8Km6JizvnYGEHzZ/nQSWmwE/F3gZaFKZRD10EWcbawb4KRjvcieqJI60FphjhvvLGO/oRRToIjZWDpwGzDY/k1QSV1oDPGt+XgK6VBJRoItY/HzGeAd+LnA2xrtwPUKX3SUx3r0/AzyF8Q4+o7KIAl2k8MJm7/s889Ooksgg7DCD/Z9mD75PJREFukj+1AAXAh8BzmDPlc9EhqIfeB74G/A4xhK3Irahx5FiFw3Ah8wQP1XnruRAEf9+0pPEeN/+N+BRjGVtRdRDFxmiaozpSZdjjEr3qiRSAGmMUfMPmAHfrpKIAl3kwIoxHqdfhjGwLaSSiIXEgafNcH+c9+5cJ6JAF52HGIu7XAN8FGM7UBGr6wEeAX6PsaiNRsuLAl1cayxwlfk5WOUQG1sP/NH8aCEbUaCLK/iBC4BrMR6p+1QScZA0xhz3e4AnMAbXieStcRXJh1HAdWaQj1I5xKG8wAfNz3bgXjPct6s0oh662Pr8wpgnfr3ZK9cNpLhRCmMA3a+A59C7dsnh3aRIthWbvfFlGKtvXawwFxfzmdfAv8xr4jrzGhFRoItlNQI/wBgUdDdwhEoi8h5HmNfGFuA2tFSxKNDFYiZjTN3ZCNwE1KokIvtVC/wnsAn4g3kNiSjQpWBOwFgWczlwNRBUSUQGJYAxbXMF8BhwokoiCnTJpw8CLwMLgIt0HokMmwdjhcT55rX1QZVEFOiSS+dh7CX9FMba6iKSfbPMa+w185oTUaBL1noO5wOLMPaMnqGSiOTFDPOaW4Qx7dOjkogCXYbqg8BCjBWvjlE5RAriGIx57IuAc1UOUaDLYMzEeI/3lIJcxDI+ADyJsZXrTJVDFOiyP0eavfF56B25iFWdbF6jT5jXrIgCXd41FrgPeBPjfbmIWN/55jV7v3kNiwJdXKwUY2W31cAVOh9EbNmGX2Zewz8wr2lRoIuL+IFPAWswVnbTutIi9lZsXstrgE+jvRMU6OIKpwJvYGzrOFLlEHGUkcBvgMXmtS4KdHGgUcADwAtoII2I000FXjSv+TEqhwJdnCGIsQnEauATaHEKETf5BLAK+Bbaa0GBLrZ2BsamD7ehwTIiblUK3Gq2BWeoHAp0sZc64E/As8BElUNEzLbgObNtGKFyKNDF2jwYo9dXA1eix+sisqcrgbeAa9VGKNDFmiZhLNd6L1CtcojIflQD92AsIztJ5VCgizX4gK8CSzCWhBQRGaiTzLbja2juugJdCmoKsAC4HS0OIyJDUwz8BJhvtimiQJc88gPfxlg8QvuTi0g2zDDblG+rt65Al/yYhLHT0vfRvFIRya6g2bbMQ+/WFeiSMx7gcxi7Kx2ncohIDh1ntjXXo5HwCnTJqpHAU8BdQFjlEJE8CAP/C/wf0KhyKNBl+C4ElgPnqBQiUgBnA8uAi1QKBboMTRFwJ/AoUKNyiEgB1QD/AH5ptk2iQJcBOgx4Ffg8en8lItbgAW4AXgMOVzkU6HJg12DsV36USiEiFnQk8DrGMtOiQJe9CAO/B36HBr6JiPXbq3vNNkvtlQJddjMRY8W3q1UKEbGRqzFeD2pXRwW6AB/BeHylR+wiYkdTzTbsEpVCge5WPuC/gYeBcpVDRGysHPir2ab5VA4FupvUYCzW8BU0il1EnMFjtmnPoKm2CnSXOBJYCMxWKUTEgc4w2zi9RlSgO9qlGIPfJqgUIuJgEzC2Y71UpVCgO40HuAV4EChROUTEBUrMNu8W9GpRge4QRcADwHd0UouICzsz3zHbQC0Zq0C3tQbgJeDjKoWIuNjHgZfNNlEU6LYzFWPNY+1dLiICM8w2capKoUC3kzOAecBYlUJE5F1jzbbxTJVCgW4HVwBPocViRET2phx40mwrRYFuWd8A/gQEVQoRkX0Kmm3lN1UKBbrV+IBfAD9CI9lFRAbCA/wQ+CVaLlaBbqE7zQeA/1ApREQG7QazDdWTTQV6QYWBx9FqSCIiw3Gp2ZZqb3UFekFUAc8CZ6sUIiLDdrbZplapFAr0fGoAXgROVClERLLmRIzFuLQAjQI9L0ZhrHiknYRERLLvSLONHa1SKNBzaRwwB5ikUoiI5MwkM9THqRQK9FyYYJ5g2vpURERtrgJdd4siIjJA4zDeqeupqAI9KyZiDIDT+xwRkfwbY7bBE1UKBfpwHAy8ADSqFCIiBdNotsUHqxQK9KEYBzyvnrmIiCWMNttkvfpUoOvEERFxQEfrBXW0FOgDVY8e7YiIWNUEs42uVykU6PtTgbH0oAZfiIhY10Szra5QKRToexMGngamqhQiIpY31WyztaGLAv09gsA/gONVChER2zjebLu19aoCHQAf8GfgLJVCRMR2zjLbcJ8CXX4BXKIyiIjY1iVmW65Ad7FvAp/TtSAiYnufM9t0BboLXQ7cpmtARMQxbjPbdgW6i5wO/A7w6PwXEXEMj9m2n65Ad4epwN/RqEgREScKmm2866Yguy3Q64B/osUIREScrAJ40mzzFegOFAaeAMbqXBcRcbwxZpvvmoVn3BLoHuAe4Did4yIirnEccC8uGS/llkC/BbhM57aIiOt8Avi+At0ZLgFu0jktIuJa38IFC4g5PdCPBP6ApqeJiLiZx8yCIxXo9lSLsWi/duIREZGwmQm1CnR78QF/ASboHBYREdMEMxscuZGLUwP9duBMnbsiIvI+Z5oZoUC3gY8CN+qcFRGRfbjRzAoFuoVNwkVzDkVEZEg8wG/NzFCgW1AYeBgt6yoiIgdWDjyCgwZOOynQ78LhUxJERCSrpprZoUC3kE8CV+ncFBGRQboKuFaBbg1TgF/onBQRkSH6HzNLFOgFFAb+ihaPERERl2eJ3QP9p064qxIRkYKbAtyhQC+MDwGf1TkoIiJZ8hngYgV6fo3EmEMoIiKSTfcCjQr0/PAAvwOqdd6JiEiWVZsZY7sFyuwY6NcD5+icExGRHDnbzBoFeg5NAn6ic01ERHLsJ9hsaVg7BbofuA9NURMRkdwLm5njV6Bn3zeBGTrHREQkT2YA31KgZ9cU4Ns6t0REJM++hU3WO7FDoPswRhyGdF6JiEiehcwM8inQh+8r6FG7iIgUzgwzixTow3AY8F86l0REpMD+CzhUgT40HuBuoEjnkYiIFFgRcA8WXnDGyoF+LXCyziEREbGIk4FPKdAHZwTwI507IiJiMT82M0qBPkA/RWu1i4iI9VSbGaVAH4AzgSt0zoiIiEVdAcxWoO9fCLhL54qIiFjc/2Kx9VGsFuhfAibqPBEREYubaGaWAn0vRgE36RwRERGbuAkYo0Df0x1Aqc4PERGxiVIsNEDOKoF+GnCpzg0REbGZS8wMU6BjLHh/p84JERGxqTuxwOYtVgj0TwFH6HwQERGbOgILrCBX6EAvA27RuSAiIjZ3C1Du5kD/BlCv80BERGyu3sw0Vwb6WODLOgdERMQhvmRmm+sC/VagWMdfREQcotjMtoLwTH1ocyH+v0cBi7H29q0iUmBBr4eRJT5GlfgZWxpgbKmfuiIf1UVeygNeSs3P3jaoTmcgkkjTk0jTGU/THkvR1Jdia0+SbT1JtvcmaY4mSWdUZ8mqNDAdWJrv/7G/gL1zhbmIvEdVyMvEiiDTakJMrgoyqTJAbZGPIp9nSF+vMrTvZqYnkaYlmuLtzgQrO2Is3hVjY3eS3mRaB0KGw2tm3Plu6KGfBMzVMRcRgAnlAWaMKOLE+iKmVAepKyrcdN7tvUmWtMVY0NzPwpZ+dkZTOkAyVCcD85we6HPMb1REXGpUiZ/TGos5Y1SYqTVBgl6P5f6NkUSaxa0xntnWx7zmKJ0x9dxlUOblO+vyHejnAP+n4yziPl4PnFBfxMUHlXJifRGlAfu8dWvtT/Hi9iiPbuphRXvcFcerNOBlYkWAN3fFdPIO3XnAU04MdA+wCPiAjrGIe4T9Hs4ZU8JHJ5RyRHXQ1t9LOgMLW/p5cH2El3ZEHTug7rTGYr44tZLHNvXy+7e7dRIP3WLgGCAvZ0o+B8WdpzAXcY9iv4fzx5Zw+cQyJpQHHPOU4fj6Io6vL+LNXTHuWxPhhR19jgn2I2tCXHdYOac0FpPOwDNb+3QiD8904ELgMScFuge4WcdWxPk8wPnjSvjUYeWOCfK9Obo2xNG1IRbvinH3qi4W7Oy37fdycHmAqw4t5/yxYfzmeIa5zVF29CV1Qg/f94DH89FLz1egn2s+dhARBzu6NsQNUyqYMaLIPV2w2hC/njWCp7f2cdfKLjZFErb5t08oD3DZIWVcMK6EYv97ByY+tqlXJ3R2TAMuAh7N+c10nt6hLwSO1XEVcaaKoJfPTq7gE4eUYcEB63kTSaT57epu7lsTIWHh5/AHlwe4bKIR5Hub47+tN8mHn2miP6VVd7LkDTMDc1rQfPTQz1WYizjXrJHFfO2oKsaV+V1fi7KAlxunVnLKyGJ+vKSDVR3WGhF/dG2ISw8u5YxR4f0u1vOPjT0K8+z6gJmFT9q9h/4yMEvHs3AXsN/jYVFrv4ohWRXyefj8EZVcMdHdvfJ9iSYz/GJFJ39eGynovyPo9XDSyCIumVDGCfVFBzxWPYk0Fz/TpEV1sm9urrMw17fUJyjMC8frga9Pq2JU2M/Hn29mR68GuEh2jC8LcMux1UyrCakY+1Ds9/D1aVVMqw1x2+IO2mP5DcjGEj8fHBPm/HElHDyIwYmPbepVmOfGycCJwAK7Bvo3dAwL5/RRYaZUGfN+bz++lute3klfUo/RZHhObSzme8dUUx3yqRgDcNboMBMrAty0sC3ni9KEfB6OG1HE+eNKOKlh8Iv39CbT3LcmooOW20y8KFdfPJeP3CcDKwA9jCuAkM/D/Wc0MKni33fmz2zt42uv7lJxZMiumlTOl4+q1EU9BJFEmu+93s6z27I7t9sDTKkOcsaoMGeMKmZ82dCnCv55bYSfLOnQwcqdDHAEsMpuPfSvK8wLZ9bI4veEOcDZY8I09VVyx7JOFUgGHRpfPaqKKyeVqRhDVBbwcvvxtdy+tIP7h/le3euBQyuDnDKymFkji5lcFRz2OIbOeFqrwuXnUvoGcJWdAn0k8Akdu8LweuDqQ8v3+ntXH1rOzmhq2A2KuIff6+GWY6o5f1yJipGFa/Mb06qoCHq5a2XXoP5uid/LlOogJ9QXMbOhiEkVwawORvzd6m5a9e48Hz4OfBNoskugXw8EddwK49i6IqbuZ83sr0+roq0/xdNa1lEOoMjn4fbjazmlsVjFyKLPTq6gLODlx/t5vO3zwEHlAY6sDnF8fRFH1QQZGc5Nk72+O8Ff1ukmP0+CZkZ+xw6BXgx8VsescD52cOl+f98DfP/YGrriaV7Zqelssnchn4f/PqGWWSMV5rlw+cQyMvDuO+vSgJfRJX6mVAc5sjrIkTUhxpb6CeRhTuDtSzuIad55Xu/pgNuAqNUD/QqgVserMEaX+Dl5AA1wyOfhx8fXcv3cFtdsBykD5/PALcfUKMxz7IqJZYwM+/B7PEysCNBYkv/Fef62oYcFzbqxz7NaMyvvyeYXzfaGxB7gRh2rwjlnbJiQb2B39JVBL/9zYp2jN9CQofnW9Go+ODasQuTBGaPCnNJYXJAw39Gb5OfLO3UQCuNGsjxwPNuBPhtjupoUgN/r4YNjBjdwqa7Yx50z67Rsp7zrs5MruGRCqQrhcOkM3PJGO13xtIpRGJPNzLRsoH9Ox6iAZ0dVkIkVg+9tjy31c+fMOuqKtVCI231wbJjrp1SoEC7wu7e7bb3lq1Pun60a6KOB83V8Cue0YYxEPqgswC9n1lFXpFB38w3hdz9QrUK4wGst/YOeNic5cYGZnZYL9GvJ3/7q8j4+D8xsGN4e1IdXBfnlSXXUKtRdpyzg5dYZNZT4vSqGw23vTfKdRW0k0xrVbgF+MzstFeh+4Dodm8IZXxbgkCwMbnsn1NVTd5dvHl01qA08xJ6iyQxfe3UXzX1aQMZCrstWZzhbgX4h0KjjUjjTa0P4szRfdbIZ6qNK9MDFDS4cX8IFWgXO8dIZ+PaiNk1TtZ5GM0MtE+if1jEprGPqirL69Q6vCvKbWSMYU6pQd3RLUuLnq0dVqRAucNub2d8YRrImKxmajUAfTZaH3svgBLweJldlf6XdsaV+fnXyiD02eRHn+OpRlVQG9d7c6X6+vJOH1vdk/esOdM0LOaDZwFgrBPrVZH/6mwzmjqrET2NJbt55vxPq02pCKrTTWpDRYc4cpcVjnO5/lnfyu9XZ3UWtOuTjU4eV89nJmuKYJV7g/xU60D1moEsBHVwRyOl6z3XFPu46uW7Yo+jFOkoDXr50ZKUK4YKe+W+zGOZHVAf5xrQqHj6rgRumVPDkll4VOXuuZpgrxw33BenJwME6DoU1MQ+PxEsDXn5+Yh3fe71dF7EDXDGxjNEa9OhY6QzcuridhzcM/zF7bZGPWSOLOXdsmGPqit7dsvXbi9pY15VQsbPYNzMzdU6hAv0aHYPCO6gsP++4Qz4Ptx1XQ12xjz+83a3C21RD2MeVk8pUCIeKJNLc/Ho7zw1jAFxpwMsxdSHOHhPmxPpiqkLvfZj75JZeHt+kG/sc+GShAj0MfET1Lyyvh7z2tDzAl4+spL7Yx+1LO9DaFPZzzaHllAU07MWJtvQk+dbCNpa1xQb9dytDXqbVhDi1sZgT6ov2uff6lp4kP36zQ8XOjQ9j7JU+pLux4STBBYBu8wusyOehvgBrsF8+sYyGsI/vLGqnJ6HNHexidImfi8Zr4xUnerkpyi1vtNMaHfiiMePLAkyvDXHSyCKm1YQOuEpkLJXhpoVtdGpDl1wpM7P1r/kO9MtU+8KrDPkoK9C0ozNGhakv9vOfC3exOZLUwbCBTxxSRtivqUZOksrAPW918etVXQd8YtYQ9nFoRZBjRoT4QG0REysCg5p69j/LO1k6hN6/DDpb8xro1cA5qnvhVYe8BL2Fa6CPqA5y7yn1fHdRG69o5yZLqy3yaUU4h9nQneDWxR0sat3z2iv2e2gM+5lUGWBKVYija0OMK/VTPsQOwFNbevnz2oiKnnvnmBnbnq9A/ygQVN0LryLoxVvgDld9sY9fnFTHHUs7eWCdLnirOn9cCZUhvTt3gkgizYPrerj7rS5iqQyVIS+jS/yMKfUzqSLIoZUBxpYGGF3iz0r7sLozzg8W6715ngTNjL07X4H+CdXcGqwyuCno9RgbfFQEuH1JB/0pjZazkoDXw0Xj1Tt3gmQ6w8KWfjweuHVGDeNK/TSE/ZQFcnNz3xFL85+vtWmsTH5dlq9AbwBmqd4WuZWz2NKLl0woZWJFgJsXtbMxojmqVjFjREi7qTmE3+vhjDyt8JcyN3RZ361rOc9ONrO2eTB/aSjduw+hpV4to8KC63BPqwnxu1NHcNZoLStqFeeNVe9cBu/2JR3MbYqqEPnnBS4eyl8aLM09lwOqKfLx3yfU8uUjK3O6LK0cWFXIy0kNxSqEDMqf1kQ0JqawBp21gw30GuBU1VkG6upDy/nNrBF63FtAx9cXaTCcDMrTW/u4Y5kGwRXYKUBtLgP9Ioa/XKy4zDF1IX5/Wj0f0qCswrQKI9U7l4F7raWfm19v0yqQhecHLsxloF+sGltLxiYXXWXQyy3H1vCDY2sOuBqVZI+xJrd2yZOBWdEe52uv7iKaVJpbxIdzFeglwBmqr7V02WwJxgvHl/CH0+o5tVG9xnw4vDLIiGLdQMmBre9O8JVXdtEZ0/Q0CzkTGPBazYMJ9NmAWmGLseN877Glfu6cWcd/Hl015FWrZGBmjAipCHJAW3qS3DC3laY+LeFsMSEz1LMe6OepttbTbeNNEj5xSBn3n97AKeqt58yRNQp02b8dfUluXNDKDoW5VQ04ewca6B7gXNXVeiKJtK0Hr4wr8/OLmXV89wPV1OndelaVB71MrNDsAtm3pr4k/zGvlXVdWjjGws41MzhrgX400Ki6Wk9bf8oRy6x+dEIpfz6jXpuHZNHYUj81ukmSfdgUSXD9XIW5DTSaGZy1QNfjdovqiqdt/dh9dyPDfm6dUcP/nlTHoZXa+2e4JlYE0ZI+sjfruxN8dk6rlnS1jwFNXxtooJ+telpTLJVhZ9RZ775OHlnMn06r5wtTKy25tK1dTCjXkhGyp+XtcT49p0XvzO1ldrYCvRw4TvW0pgywtcd5F2ax38O1h5Vz/xkNXDCuBK0eO3jjSvX+XN5rfnM/N8xtoTWaUjHs5TigIhuBfipaHc7SNjj4sdnYUuMx/N2zRjC9ViO2B8rrgVElumzl357Y3MuNC1rpjGueuQ35GMCy6wMJ9LNUS2tb44JBLTNGFPH70+r54XE1Whd+AEr8XmqK9LpCDPeu7uamhW3EUloBzsYOmMUDuYWfrTpa28ZIglgqQ8jn7OfSHoxtQE9vDPPIhh7uXxvRe8B9qAp5CfsV6G4XT2f40ZsdPLKhR8WwvwNm8YGu+LHAJNXR2rb3Jtnc455gK/Z7uHJSGQ+e2cD1Uyo0f30vyoNeghp44Got0RSfn9eqMHeOicC44QT6Kaqh9aUzsLI95rrvuzLk5bOTK3j4LAX7+5UFvBpI6GJL2mJ86uWdvLKzX8VwllOGE+izVD97eL015trvvTrk47OTK3hwthns2oyEIp/S3K3+vrGHz8xpYXNEr6McaL+ZfKB36Oqh28Qbu2L0pzKubsjrioxgv2RCKY9v7uVvG3rY0uPORq0ypJsat+lNprl9SSd/36hH7Oqh76kR45m92EBTb5K3OuIqBFBT5OOaQ8t5aPZI/uuYaqZUuW/VOfXP3WVlR5xPvdSiMHe+Q9jPMuzeoXbtxVoywNzmqAqxm7Dfw8UHlXLf6fXcObOOUxqL8evFsjjQncs7WaUbereYNZRAP0l1s5c5O6Jomume/F4PpzYW84uZdTxwRj2XTyzTADpxFI/uUxXo7P8d+vGqm72s7UqwvD3GNO2BvU+HVQY5bFqQ6w4v57ltUZ7Y3MvStpgKI7amQZCuMmOwgR4GjlLd7CUDPLWlT4E+ANUhH5ceXMqlB5eypC3G01v6eHFHlCaHLFSTSOtRjZuUB7SIkIscZWZ03/t/Y19nwTFo/XZben5bH5GE1moejGk1Ib55dBUPz27gJ8fXcuaoMGU2byC7tF63627mxTX8ZkYPuIeux+021dqf4rltfVx8UKmKMdheTtDLOWPCnDMmTFNfkrlN/bywo483d8WIJu3VZPZrMIWIkx0PzFGgu8DDG3q4aHypVgobhpFh/7uP5Lf2JFmws58XtvextC1Gnw3CPZJIk86gc0DEuYE+4B669j+3sRXtcV5t6efE+iIVIwvGlPr5WGkpHzu4lB29SRa1xpjXHGXxrphl95XujqeJptKUaIMWESc6dqCBXs9+Jq6LPfx+dbcCPQcaS/xcVOLnovEldMbTrGyP88rOKK+3xljfnbDM9pQdsRR9iQzaEl3EkUabWb3zQIE+TbWyv9da+nmtpZ/jRijUc6Uy6GVmQxEzG4wab44kWdIW443Wfpa3x9nSkyzYaPNoMkNLf0rr2os41zTgmQMF+nTVyRnueatbgZ5H48r8jCszeu+pDGzsTrCyI86SthirO+JsiiTpTeZn9HkG2NaTdOWytyIuMX0ggX606uQMC1v6eWlHlFMbi1WMPPN54JCKAIdUBLhofAnpjDED4e3OOOu6EqzoiLMpkmBrTzJnj+k3RRI6ECLOtUdW65G7w925opMT6osIaSWpgvJ6oL7YR31xMbNGGjdYiXSG1miKTZEkGyIJ1ncnWN+VoLU/RWs0RXyYj+vXdyvQRRxs2oECvQxjNxdxiHVdCf6yLsLVh5arGBYT8HpoLPHTWOLnxIZ/vxrpTaZpjabYGU2xpSfJ9t4kTX1JmvtStERT9CTS9CTSB1y3f2VHnGQ6ow1pXEALCbnSIWZmR/YV6FPQzouOc89b3ZwxKsyYUg15toMSv5eSMi/jywIcN+K9vxdPZ+iKpWmPpeiKp+mIpdnVn6IjlqYtZoR9JJGmN2GkfVssTb0GxjleUnnuRh4zs1/dV6BPVo2cJ5JI85OlHfxiZp2KYXNBr4e6Yt+ARq8n0xm82obLFeJau9+tJu8e6F4Fuju8vCPKwxt6VAgX8Xs9WinOJWJa6tfNgY4C3YV+tqyTjRr5LOIoiXSGPj1zd6sp+wv0KaqPc/Uk0nx3Ubvu5kUcFejqoauHvmeglwFjVB9nW9oW46fLOlUIEYeIpzP0JBToLjXWzO49Av0QNMLdFR5cF+ERvU8XcYRYKpO3FQjFkg7ZW6BPUl3c48dLOljY0q9CiNhcJJ4u2J4BYgnj9xboE1QXd93Vf+O1NtZ2aZCciJ11xtMoz13toL0F+kTVxV3a+lN8aUErTX1JFUPEroEeS6kI6qHvEeha8tVmsjHgYUtPkhvmKdRF7Ko9pvfnCvQ9A12P3G2mMuTlOx+oZmr18LbIXNeVUKiL2FRrv3roCvT3BnoRMEp1sZcMcOG4En5/Wj23HFvD4cPY+/qdUN+hUBexlZaoAt3lJrw/0DX/3IYSKePuPOj18KHxJdx/ej3/fUItM0YUDTnUP/1yC2s0UE7ENnbqJtztSoA6BbrNJTOZ90xX8Xs9nDU6zL2njOC+0+u59ODSAW3isbstPUk+/XILr+zUlDYRq0tloEWP3MUc6a5At/nFnNjHeJijakJ8e3o1fztrJD85vpYzRoWpCnkH9HXbYyk+P6+Vh9Zr8RkRK4sk0nRpUJyY79Hf2T51rOphwx56OkNvYv8Xc2XQyzljwpwzJkxrf4rFrTFe2dnPm7tibO1NktzHBNZ4OsMPFrezpivOV46sotivRQRFrKYrlqYzrkCX9wb6aNXDngaz5GNdkY+zx4Q5e0yYZDrDhkiS1R1xlrXHWN+dYHMkSWc8/Z6Qf2h9D2+0xrj5mGqm1YRUcBEL2RlNapU42SPQ9cjdplqHOMLV7/UwqSLApIoAF44vAYzd2Jr7UmzvTbIzmqK5L0lLf4qm3hS/faubaw8v5yiFuohlbO3RgDjZM9BHqB721JzFKSulAS+HVHg5pCKw19/v1xaNIpayWYEuu2X4O6OkGlQPe2rqzd8FXeTTe3QR9dDFghp2D/Q61cOetvdqyoqIG6UzsLlHa0bIvzPcC1QDQdXDpoHel9SjcBEXautPaZU4eUcQqPWqd25vLdGU1mAXcaHmaIqIpqzJv9V6gUbVwb6S6QwbuvXYTcRtNnYn0LM52c1IL1CpOtjbyo64iiDiMqs7dd3Le1Qq0B1geZsubBG30ZM5UaA70NtdcS3/KOIi/akMGyIKdFGgO05nLM3KdvXSRdxia09yyKtEirMDvUp1sL9XdkZVBBGXWNsVR7NVRT10h5rf3L/PndNExFmW64mc7CPQK1QH+9sYSfBWp96pibiBRrjLvgJd22c5QDoDL2zvUyFEHK4jlmZdl27eZQ8hL1CiOjjDC9uj2htZxOHWdsXp0qwW2VOJAt1BNkYSLGyJqRAiDrZU607IfgJdj9wd5B8be1QEEQdb0qabdtmrkBcoVR2cY25zlO292qxFxIl6EmkNiJN9KfUCYdXBOaLJDI9sUC9dxIne6oxrQRnZl7AXCKgOzvKPjb20x3TRizjN4lY9bpd9CnhVA+dpj6X463r10kWcZpECXfZDge5Qf13XQ0dMU1tEnKK1P8Vb2ipZDhDofpXBmb30+9Z2qxAiDrGiPU4koZt02SctLONkf1nbwzaNeBdxhPnN2oBJ9qtIj9wdrDeZ5pcrulQIEZtLpjNaNEoOSIHucP+3pZf5zf0qhIiNvd2VYEuP1m8XBbqrZYDbl3bQl9Qa7yJ2Na8pirZpkIEEeq/K4GwbuhP8epUevYvY9aZ8np6yyYH1ewGNmnKB+9Z08+pONQoidrO1J6npajIQMT1yd4lUBm55o11z00VsZm5TlLiet8sAKNBdZFtvku8vblchRGzkhe2ariYDD3QNnXSR57b1cfdbep8uYgdbepIsa9d0NRmQhBfoUx3c5a6VXTy/XYddxOrmNkWJpfS4XQakzwtoFw+XSWfgO4vaWamBNiKWlQGe2aobbxmwHi+g5zluPPKJNF9a0MqWHk1yELGi9V0J3XTLYMQ0D93FmvtS/Me8Vlqj2jtdxGqe3d5HQqPbZeB6FegutymS4AvzW2nrV6iLWEUyneFfetwuQwh0PXJ3uZUdcT4/v5XmPoW6iBUs3hVjfbcmIMmgxLyA5jAJK9rjfGZOC5siakRECu2JzXpwKoPW5QU6VQcB2BhJ8Jk5rSxp00MbkULpiKV5eYcWk5FB61Sgy3s09SX53JxWTZcRKZDntvfRGdcSzTL4e0Ev0KE6yO56k2m+9uou7dAmkmcZ4NGNWhpE1EOXLLtrZRdfnN9Ki6a1ieTF0rYYK9o191wU6JIDL+6IcvWLO3m5Se/0RHLtHxt70cxzUaBLzmzrTfKFea3cvrSDbr3bE8mJ1miK57Zp7IoML9CbVAc5kAxw35oIV7ywU9s5iuTAE5t7iSR0wyxD1uQFWlQHGahNkQQ3Lmjl66/uYl2X5qyLZEMsleHvGgwnw7PLC7QDGoUhg/L01j4uf6GZny7t1KA5kWF6cUdUGyXJcCTeCXSAVtVDBiuazPDHNd1c+mwzd67o1NKxIkOQzsADayMqhAxHC8A7gd6seshQtcdS3PtWN5c+18SPl3SwVo/iRQbs9dZ+rc4ow9UM4N893UWGozOW5v61Ef66vocT64u4cHwJJ9YXURrwqjgi+3CfeueSpR76O4G+TfWQbEmmM8xpijKnKUpjiZ+TGoo4vTHMtNoQYb9HBRIxreyIM1drPMjwbds90LeqHpILO3qTPLS+h4fW9zC6xM+xI4o4ob6IKVVBRoZ9+L0KeHGvP63pJq2VZGT4tu4e6FtUD8n5LWRvkm0be/iHOT3nmLoQF4wr4dyxJYR8CnZxl7VdCZ7dpt65ZD/Q1UOXdzWEfRxaEWRLT5LmaJJocvhdiLKAl5FhH40lfg6vCjKxIsCEsgAjin0Kc3Gl+9dGSKp7Lgp0ySWvx8PPTqwllTH2Zm7tT9Hcl6QlmqIznqYzlqIvmSGRztBtrmzl83ioDHrxeKA84KUy5KUy6KOu2MfIsI+aIh9VQa8esYsAGyMJntzSq0JItmxRoMte7ehNMre5n9Mai2kI+2gI+5haHVRhRLLkN6u6iaXUO5fs9tDfmU/UD+xQTeQd/6feg0hOrOlK8Kw2YZEs9sHMDGf3CcLrVRd5x7zmfnZqSVeRrLv3rS4Sencu2fNudu8e6OtUF3lHTyKtXrpIli1ti/Ev9c4lD4G+VnWR3f19Y6/e84lk0a9WdmneuWTb2r0F+gbVRXa3KZJgjlaxEsmKOU1RFuzsVyEkLz30NaqLvN8f10TUoxAZplQGfrmiS4WQvPXQ1wFquuU9lrXFeFm9dJFh+fvGHlZ3xlUIyVugR9B8dNmL367WetMiQ9UZT/ObVeqdS05sMbN7j0AHWKn6yN566RqZKzI0v1vdTYumgEpurNr9F979/abIO+5a2ZWVNd1F3GRtV4K/rNN+56JAFwvZFElwvxomkUH52bJOTf0UBbpYz2/f6mZTJKFCiAzA01v7mNesAaVSuEBfiUa6yz70JtPcvrRThRA5gO54mp8v07UiOZXhfePe3h/oEbQErOzH3KYof9/Yo0KI7MevVnWxoy+pQkgurQe69xfoAEtUJ9mfO5Z16tG7yD4saYvxoMabSO69+f7/4B3IHxLZXXc8zc2vt2vHKJH3iacz3La4A42DE6sE+mLVSQ54Ju2KcedyLZYhsrs/vN2tFeEkXxYPJNCXqE4yEH9c080Tm7XFqgjAWx1x7nmrW4WQfFkykEDfCTSpVjIQP1jcztK2mAohrpZMZ/j+4nbNOZd82W5m9QEDHeBV1UsGIprM8LVXd7G1RyN6xb1+u7qbFe161C55s3Bv/1GBLsPW3JfiK6/soq1f61WL+yxri3Hvaj1ql7x6VYEuObO6M86XFuyiN5lWMcQ1oskM33tDj9rF2oH+OqBnqDIoS9pifGnBLvq0iYu4xB3LOljXpTUZJK+SZkYPOND7gKWqmwz6tnFnP1+c30pHTD11cbbntvfx1/VaNVHybpmZ0QMOdIDXVDcZitda+rlhXgtNWvpSHGpHb5IfvNGhQkhBmth9/cb+An2u6iZDtaI9zmfmtGqRDXGcZDrDza+30x7TIFApiLlDCfQ5qpsMx6ZIgutebuHlJm0hKc7xq1VdvNbSr0JIobw8lEDfAaxV7WQ4uuJpvji/ld9pWo84wEs7ovxW57IUzjozmwcd6OqlS1akM/Dz5Z185ZVdtGquutjUlp4kN7/ehvYkEiv2zhXoklfPbuvjmhd3MleP4MVm+lMZ/vO1XZq9IYU2ZziB/pLqJ9nu5fzHvFZ+vKSD7rgaR7GH2xa3s1xLu4rNe+hbgDWqoWRTBrh/bYQrXtjJs9v6VBCxtD+tifDoJu0qKAW3Ftg8nEAHeE51lFzYFEnwlVd28YX5razqUO9HLNgdaorys2Waby6W8OyB/sBAAv1fqqPk0ks7olz14k5uXdzOFu3aJlbpDnUl+M6iNrRMu9gl0D1TH9p8oD9TAewC/Kqn5FppwMtF40u49OBSDioLqCBSEO2xFNe82MLGiNZpF0tIATVA13ADHWAeMFM1lXwp8nmYPTrMRyaUMr02pIJI3sRSGa6f28qiVi0eI5axYCAZPNBe9zMKdMmn/lSGJzb38sTmXqbXhjhvXAmnjiymrtin4khOfe/1doW5WM2zA/lDA+2hTwfeUE2lkCqDXk5oKOL0xjDT60LUFSncJbvuWNbJH97WSnBiOceyjy1ThxLoHmAb0Ki6ihVUBL0cUR3kuBFFTK8NcUhFkLDfo8LIkP1xTTc/XdqpQojV7ABGY8z43a+BPnLPAE8B16q2YgVd8TTzm/uZ32w8Gm0I+5hYEWRiRYApVUFGlfhpDPspD3rxKuflAB7d1KswF6t6aiBhPphAB3hSgS5W1dyXorkv+u6ysl4PVAZ9VIa8NIR91ISMn1cEvRT5vFSFvMweHabIp7R3u+e29fG919tUCLGqJwf6BwcT6M8BUaBY9RWrS2eMqUftsRQbut879agy6OW7x1QTVNfd9V5uinLTIm24IpYVYxCLu3kH8YV7gOdVX7GzWSOL+evsBs4cFdajeJd7c1eMb77aRjSpNBfLet7M3qz30AH+AZyvGovdBLwePje5gk8eVq4gF5a0xfjC/FZ6k9ogSCztb4P5w95BfvHHAK3NKbYyqSLA3bNGcO3hCnMxeuZfmNdKl3b7E2tLAo8P5i8MtofehrGl6pmqtVid1wOXHVLG9VMqKA14VRDhzV0xvriglU6FuVjfyxjLrucs0N95BKBAF0ubUB7g60dVcWJDkYohACzeFePGBa10xhTmYgt/G+xfGEq35VFAV4RYks8DV04q40+n1SvM5V1zm6JcP7dFYS52kcYYszYoQ+mhNwNzgFNVc7GS6bUhvji1kqO1mYvs5rntfdy0UKPZxV73oGbW5jzQAf6iQBerqCvy8cnDyvn4IWVonRjZ3WObevne69rTXGzngaH8pYGu5f5+1UATEFTdpVB8HvjIhFI+fXgFI7QLm7zPn9ZE+O+lHSqE2E0cGAm056uH3g48DVyo2kshnNZYzHWHV3BEte4pZU//s7yT367WrmliS08PJcyHE+jvPBJQoEteHVMX4trDKjTgTfYqlspwyxvtPLG5V8UQu3pgqH9xOIH+BBABylR/ybWja0NcObGM07Vkq+zDrv4U317YxoKd/SqG2FXEzNa8B3ofxjy5q3UMJFem1YS4clIZZyjIZT/WdCX45mu7WNeVUDHEzv5hZmveAx3g9wp0yYUT6ou4bGIZs0YWoxyX/XlpR5TvLmrT6m/iBL8dzl8ebqDPBdYDB+s4yHCVBrycPqqYSyaUclSN5pLLgf1xTTc/W9ap7U/FCdabmVqwQM8AfwC+r2MhQzW21M95Y0s4f1wJY0r9KogcUDSZ4UdLOvjHxh4VQ5ziD2amDtlQ56HvbjSwmaEtIysuFfZ7OG5EEeePK2FmQzFhvx6sy8BsjCT49sI2lrfHVQxxijRwELClkD10gG3As8DZOiayP14PTKkKMnt0mNNHhRmr3rgM0r+29XHr4nY6tCa7OMuzww3zbAU6wN0KdNmXw6uCnDqymFmNxUyuCmqQmwxaIp3hFyu6+MPbWixGHOnubHyRbAX648AOoFHHRYp8Hg6vCjKzoYgT640Q15QzGar13QluW9zBolbNLxdH2mFmqGUCPQncA9ysY+NOo0v8TKsNcWxdiGPqijS4TbLisU293LGsQ4/YxcnuMTN02LIxKO7dNh3YmMWbBLGooNdDQ9jHoZVBpteGmFYbYkJZgGINbJMs6YiluWNZB49t0hKu4mhJjMFw26zUQ8f8B/0T+JCOkXP4vR7qinyMK/NzWGWQwyuDTKoMMKbUT1DP0SUH5jVH+dGbHWzpSaoY4nRPZCvMsx3oAL9SoA9PyOchVoDNm8sCXmqLfNQV+xhd4uegcj9jSwOML/NTV+SjNKBZiZJbkUSaX67o4i/rIiqGuMWvs9oBy/I/7llgFTBZx2lozhwV5rRRxXTG0uyMJmmPpemKp+mOp+lJpImlMkSTGTJAMpPZa/j7PFDk85IhQ8jnwe/xUB70UhrwUhn0UhnyUhX0UVNkhHhD2E950Pi9kE+9bilMr/ynSztZ36212MU1VpmZadlAzwA/J0tD8N3oqS29xFIZvnxUJaNL9n54+pIZ0pkMqYyxYtZ7D0AGv9dDsRnMxX4vymixqtb+FL9a2cUjG7Tim7jOzxnmynDvl81Bce8oxpggX6vjNXQhn4crJ5ZxzWHllOlxtzjQE5t7+cWKTpr7UiqGuM0uYCwQzeYXzUVSRMnyewE3iqUy3Lu6m8uf38nTW/tUEHGM1Z1xbpjXyk0L2xTm4la/znaY56qHDjAS2AQEddyy46SGYq6fUsER1Sqp2FNXPM3v3+7m/rWRggz8FLGIODAeaMr2F87VnPEm4EHg/+nYZce85igLW/q5+KASrjmsnMawpvuLPaQz8NimHu55q5ttvZqKJq73YC7CPJc9dDBGuq8ALd2dbdUhH1dMKuNjB5fq/bpY2oLmfn7zVhdv7oqpGCLGILgjMEa42yrQAR4DLtQxzI2xpX6uOrScC8aVUKSh7GIhK9rj/G51N89t1/gPkd08DlyUqy+e60A/EZivY5hbkyoCfPKwcmaPDhPQ6m1SQOu6EvxxTTf/3NyLXpOL7GEmsMCugQ4wBzhZxzH3jqgOcuXEcmaPLsavYJc82hxJ8sC6CI9u6tljbQQRAWAuMCuX/4N8BPp5GGu8Sx6D/bJDypg9OqyV3ySn1ncneHh9D49v7qUnoR3RRPbjfOBJuwc6wCLgGB3P/DqkIsDHDi7j3LFhDZ6TrFrdGefBdT08aa5sKCL79QZwLFleGa5Qga5eegGNLvHz4YNKuWB8CfXFPhVEhmxhSz8PrIvw8o6o3pGLDNzFwKO5/p/kK9A9wEL10gurMujlrDFhLj6olClVWqBGBiaazPDijj4e2dDD662afiYySMuAabnunecz0AEuwBiyLwXm9cDMhmIuPqiEkxuK9Z5d9mpLT5InN/fy5JZe7U0uMnQfwpjCnfuecx4D3QO8DkzX8bWOg8oCnDMmzDljwxxUFlBBXC6RzrCwJcZjm3qY0xSlTyPWRYZjMcaT6bxcSPkMdNC7dMsK+TwcX1/EuWNKmNlQRHlQg+jcZGMkwXPbojy9tZe1XdqTXCRLcj6yvZCBDsZcvJN0nK2rvtjHaaPCnDU6zFE1QS1W41Bt/SnmN/fz9NY+FrX2a7S6SHbNI89rsBQi0E8yQ11sYGJFgFMbizmtMczkqiDKdnvrjqd5raWfZ7f1sbAlRntM25eK5MjJZqg7OtDBeOx+no63vRxWGeSUxmJOGVnM4VVBNJbOHlqjKV5vjfHCjj4W74rRGlWIi+TYkxiP2/OqUIF+FMZgAb2otSEPxqI1x9cXMbOhmCOqgnrnbjHruxMsaulnfnM/b7bF6I5rFTeRPEljDP5e6pZAB7gPuELH3v7qin1Mrw1x/IgiPlAXYmxpQI/m86ytP8WqjjgLW2K83trP2q4E8bTeiYsUwJ+BKwvS2SpgoI8FVgPFOv7OEfB6mFAe4OjaEMfWhZhSHWRk2I/yPbs6Y2nWdsdZuivOotZ+3u5M6H24SOFFgcOALW4LdIAfADfpHHCuYr+HCWUBplQHObo2xKEVQcaU+rWYzSAk0hlaoinWdiVY2hZjeXuctV1xOmJ6jC5iMbcVMtMKHejlwBqgXueBe3rw9cU+Dq0MMqkywJSqIONKAzSW+DQ9zgzvpr4UW3uSvN0Z5+2uOG93JmjqS2pbUhFr2wlMAroL9Q/wF7gA3cB3gd/oXHBPYG3rTbKtN8nz243/VuTzUFfsY3xZgAllAcaX+ZlQHqA+7KO2yEfQgUHfn8rQGk3REk2xMZJgUyTBpkiSjZEEu/pTCm8R+7m5kGFuhR76OzcVbwJH6HyQ3ZUGvNQV+RhR7GNcmZ+RYT8NYR8NxX5GFPsoDXgpCXgsF/jpDERTaXoTGTrjaVqiSXb2GeH9zs1MW7/x634t5iLiBCuAo4GCbnpghUAHOA14QeeEDPgu0OuhPOClKuSlPGj8WB3yUR3yURnyUhH0UhrwUuzzUBLwEvRC2O/F44GygHfAg/RSGYgk0niA3mSaRBp6EmliqQw9iTSRRJqueJrOWJr2WIpO8+eRRJqOmBHYGmwu4ninAy9aoXdsBS8CDwOX6LyQgUimM7THUhrZLSKF9rAVwhystbDLV4EenRsiImITfWZ2WYKVAn0LcKvODxERsYlbKdCcc6sHOsDPgLU6R0RExOLWAj+10j/IaoEeA27QeSIiIhZ3g5lZCvT9eBa4X+eKiIhY1ANmVlmKVbfI+jLQoXNGREQsph34khX/YVYN9BbgGzpvRETEYr5pZpQCfRDuBebr3BEREYuYZ2aTJVk50DPAtUC/ziERESmwfuA6M5sU6EOwGmPBexERkUK62cwky/LaoIg/BRbqXBIRkQJZiMXmnNs10FPAJ7HYfD8REXGFmJlBlt84wmuTgq5Ey8KKiEj+3WZmkOV5bVTUH6JH7yIikj8LzUC3BTsFehK4EmN3GxERkVzqMzMnqUDPjTXA13WeiYhIjn3dzBzb8NqwyHcBz+hcExGRHHnGzBpbsWOgZzBGHLbrnBMRkSxrNzMmY7d/uNemBd+BsWKPiIhINl1nZozteG1c9L8Dv9G5JyIiWfIbM1tsyWvz4n8ZWKVzUEREhuktM1Nsy+6B3gdciqayiYjI8LLkErtnidcBB2IlcKPORxERGaIbsclqcE4PdIB7gD/qnBQRkUH6k5khtud10EG5Hliuc1NERAZoOfA5p3wzTgr0PuCjQLfOUREROYBuHPDe3KmBDsYyfZ/SeSoiIgfwKeBtJ31DXgcepEeAn+lcFRGRffi5mRWO4nXowfoa8LzOWREReZ/nga868RtzaqCngI8DG3TuioiIaaOZDSkFur3sAi5Gi86IiIiRBR8ys8GRvA4/gMuAq7HhrjkiIpI1GTMLljn5m/S64EA+DNyq81lExLVuM7PA0bwuOZjfBf6ic1pExHX+AnzHDd+oWwI9A1wLvKZzW0TENV4z235XvHb1uujA9gEXANt0jouION42s813zcBor8sOcCtwLtClc11ExLG6zLa+1U3ftNeFB3o58GEgrnNeRMRx4mYb77rNurwuPeAvAJ9E09lERJwkY7btL7jxm/e6+MDfD3xL57+IiGN8y2zbXcnr8oP/I+BXugZERGzvV2ab7lpenQN8HgfuuiMi4iKPmG25qynQjUX6LweeVSlERGznWbMNT7m9EAp0Qxxj0X4tPCMiYh+vmW23Zi0p0N+jDzgbF051EBGxoeVmm60dNRXoe9UFnAWsUylERCxrndlWa5EwBfp+NQOnARtUChERy9lgttHNKoUCfSC2AacDW1QKERHL2GK2zdqTQ4E+KJt14oiIWK6jtVmlUKAPxXrzBNqhUoiIFMwOsy1er1Io0IdjLcb7GvXURUQK0zM/zWyLRYE+bGuAU9CjHhGRfNpstr1rVAoFejZtME8sjX4XEVGbq0B3wN3iqbpbFBHJqTVmW6unogr0nNpq3jUuUylERLJumdnGblUpFOj50GzePb6iUoiIZM0rZtuqRWMU6HnVAcwGnlEpRESG7V9mm9qhUijQC6EXuBB4WKUQERmyh4ELzDZVFOgFEwc+AdylUoiIDNpdZhuqLVAV6JaQAm4AvgVkVA4RkQPKmG3mDWYbKgp0S/khcJXuNEVE9itutpU/VCkU6FZ2H3AeEFEpRET2EDHbyPtUCgW6HTwHzETbr4qI7G6L2TY+p1Io0O1kOXAcsFClEBFhodkmLlcpFOh29M4CNA+pFCLiYg+jBWMU6A4QBT4OfB+NgBcRd8mYbd/HzLZQFOiOOKm/izHXUgsniIgb9AKXmW2fOjMKdMf5K8aAkI0qhYg42CazrXtQpVCgO9lS4FjgeZVCRBzoebONW6pSKNDdoA04B7hDpRARB/m52bbtUikU6G6SBL4CXAp0qxwiYmPdZlv2JbNtEwW6Kz2M8XhqhUohIja0ApiBdp1UoAsAazAWXPiDSiEiNvJHs+16W6VQoMu/9QHXANeZPxcRsXJ79WngarVXCnTZt3uBY4BlKoWIWNByjNeE96gUCnQ5sLcwHmP9L1qQQUSs4y6M9+WrVAoFugxcP/AfwMUY09xERAqlzWyLbjDbJlGgyxA8BhwJPKNSiEgB/As4CnhUpVCgy/DtAD5o3h1rAIqI5EMfxlPCc4DtKocCXbIng/H+ajraY11Ecmuh2dZoHI8CXXLobYxND74LxFUOEcmiuNm2zERzyxXokhdJjD2GPwAsUjlEJAsWYUyZ/T5avlWBLnm3AjgR+AYaeSoiQ9MPfNNsS5arHAp0KWxv/SfANGCeyiEigzAfOBr4sXrlCnSxjreBWRjLMXaoHCKyH53AZ4CTgdUqhwJdrCeDsRzj4cD9KoeI7MUDwGHA3WgEuwJdLG8ncAUwG1incoiI2RacBVxuthGiQBcbeQ44Avg20KNyiLhSr9kGTAWeVTkU6GJfMeBWYArwV5VDxFUeAiabbYBmwijQxSG2AB8HTgNWqhwijrbKvNY/Zl77okAXB3oJY4rbDUCzyiHiKK3mtX2Uea2LAl0cLomxLvxEjEdxUZVExNai5rU8wby2NadcgS4u04MxWOYwjKksaZVExFbS/Hsamga/KtBF2IIxlWU68KTKIWILT5rX7OXoPbko0OV9lgLnAycBc1UOEUuah7HC2/nmNSuiQJd9mo+xjOx5wGKVQ8QSFpshfjLat0EU6DJIT2Fsp3gh8IbKIVIQbwAXmdeiXomJAl2GLAM8ARwLXID2XxfJl0XmNXcs8Dhad10U6JLFYP8nMAM4F71jF8mVeeY1NsO85hTkokCXnPk/jHfsM9VzEMnaDfMTGANSTzavMREFuuTNAox3e0cAfwISKonIoCTMa2cqxliV+SqJKNClkFYBVwEHAT8EdqkkIvvVZl4rB5nXjvZXEAW6WMp24FvAOOAzaqRE9rDSvDbGmtfKdpVEFOhiZX3A3RiPEc8CHgVSKou4VMq8Bs4yr4m7zWtEJKv8KoHkUAZ41vyMBq4FrgMaVRpxgR3APcC9wDaVQ3LNM/WhzaqC5Psm8kKMx45noqdE4ixp4Hng1xgzQLTrmSjQxRXGYgwIugo4WOUQG1sP/NH8aKMUUaCLe89DjLm31wAfBUpVErGBHuAR4PcYCy1pPQZRoIvsJozxSP4y4GwgqJKIhcSBZzD2IH8cDW4TBbrIgFSbPfbLzB683rdLIaTNHvhfgIeBdpVEFOgiQ9cAfAj4CHAqmqEhuZUEXgL+hjHlrFklEQW6SPbVYDyW/whwBlCkkkgW9GOMUP8bxuP0NpVEFOgi+RMGZgPnA+cBI1USGYQmjD3G/4mxXoLeiYsCXcQK5zPwAeCDwDkY20/q0bzsLomxz/gzZpC/gUaniwJdxPIqgNPMHvxsYKJK4kpr+feKhS8CXSqJKNBF7G0ccIr5mQUcopI40jpgDvCy+VEjJwp0EYdrNMP9JGAmMAU9orebJMYOZvOBeWaA71BZRIEu4m4lGO/gjzc/M4BRKoul7ABeA141P28AvSqLiHojIrvrxXhUO2e3/9YATDM/083PBIwBeJI7GWAD8KYZ2kvMj+aDi6iHLpI15cBk4AjgMIw9rg/D2GxGBm8LsBpYbv64AlgFdKs0Iuqhi+RSN/9+5Pv+oJ+EMdhugvnjIRij6xtcXrNmjNHm6zB2Jltv/nyNgltEgS5ixaB/3fy8X5HZgx8DjMYYcT8a4x39SGCE+QnY7HtOAC3mpwnYDmzDGFm+bbef9+v0EFGgizhBv9kbXXOAP1ezW7jXAJV7+ZQCZeZNQrH564D5e7u/2y/byzWeBCK7/ToDdJrB3ANEzX9rxPx1514+bbuFuJZHFbGI/z8AsO1M7FKYTFgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></body></html>
```

And so the answer to OP's question:

> 1. Is hosting the image online absolutely necessary?

No.

> 2. Is there any way to bundle the image along with the HTML file without
>      having to host the image online?(I don't mind if the size of the file
>      increases)

Yes. See the explanation with example above. Read more here: [How to convert and integrate a base64 encoded image into a web page](http://picbase64.com/). The another simpler way is to convert the HTML file to [MIME HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) (using internet explorer).

> 3. If hosting must be done then please suggest a website where images can
>      be hosted easily and the upload speed is decent.

As explained, "hosting" isn't technically necessary (depending on your use case). Google "free image hosting" to find suitable hosts.

Comment: I asked this question a long time ago. (When I was very new to HTML). Now I am pretty well versed. And your solution is amazing!

Comment: @IcyFlame Glad to help. I too learnt something new - every browser seems to have developed their own way to combine and store HTML files (checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Archive_Format for more info). Something else to keep in mind - encoding an image to base64 increases the file size of the image. For example, when I encoded a 282 KB JPEG image, the base64 encoding data size was 100 KB more.

Comment: Yeah. THe size does increase but I think this is pretty handy. No external dependencies. I don't know why I needed this, but I am pretty sure that something like this can come in handy!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send it to other people on other pc's then you will have to upload the image to a website and use that link since they dont have the image on their pc. A good website to upload your picture to is [tinypic](http://www.tinypic.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can serve your images from the same location as the HTML file.

If you're just showing this to friends and family on your own machine by opening the HTML file in your browser then you can link to images in the same location.

```
<img src="myphoto.jpg" alt="Having fun in the park" />
```

or you cna put the image in a folder relative to the HTML file

```
<img src="images/myphoto.jpg" alt="Having fun in the park" />
```

This is the propper way to refer to images, even once you push the HTML file online.

Comment: then i would have to mail the complete folder?

Comment: Are you mailing the html file to your friends and family to show them?

Answer (score 0):

This may be incorrect, but I believe if you create a folder within the HTML structure. Store all images used online for it.

For example Website Folder -> Content Folder -> Images Folder (all images in here)
This is what I have been doing for the past few months whilst learning.

Comment: So you could have your tags to look like this in HTML

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to host the image.

you must include the image to the sent data though. this would normally look something like this if you have some more sites

```
rootfolder(MySite)
  -img(Folder)
    -img1.jpg
    -img2.jpg
  index.html
```

you can then reference:

```
<img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="foo bar" />
```

If you do not specify a full "physical" path from `C:/` or `~/root/` the path will automatically be set from the current location (where your displayed html-site is). you can also go up directories by using `../`

Answer (score 0):

I will answer point by point:

1. Yes. You need to link them to your file, cause they don't have access to your pc.
2. You can zip the whole package > html, css, js, images whatever you have in there.
3. If you have dropbox, drive then just use them. Other than that you can go for [photobucket.com/](http://beta.photobucket.com/)

Comment: actually both of them require accounts. whereas tinypic in the answer below does not require an account. try it. it is great!

Comment: Yeah, forgot about tinypic.

Answer (score 0):

This is what yo can do:

Create a folder "mywebsite" and in that folder have both the html file and the picture. In your html file your img src should be

```
<img src = 'whateverpic.jpg' alt = 'whatever'>
```

When you send your file file to your parents, zip the "mywebsite" folder so that you keep both the html and picture under the same location.