# Can anyone explain how can I store images locally in Var

Tags: javascript, localhost, var

Please help, im running a script I found here :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img alt="slideshow" src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/253822/156271139.jpg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" />
    </div>
</div>
<script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img alt="slideshow" src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/253822/156271139.jpg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" />
    </div>
</div>
<script>

    var imgs = ["http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/253822/156271139.jpg", "http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/554278/132632972.jpg", "http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/101304/133879079.jpg", "http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/422038/422038,1327874090,3.jpg", "http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/975647/149914934.jpg", "http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/195826/148988282.jpg"];

function changeImage(dir) {
    var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right -> show next image
        changeImage()
    }
}
```

The thing is I trying to run it locally / offline. So how do I run it like this

```
var imgs = ["pic1.gif", "pic2.gif", "pic3.gif", "pic4.gif", "pic5.gif"];
```

Its driving me insane :)

Please help Many Thanks

Comment: You have an extra `<script>` tag before the second `container` DIV.

Comment: Wondered why i couldn't format it correct. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to run a server and host the images locally. So your links will look something like `localhost:1339/photos/thumb_large/253822/156271139.jpg`.

Edit: Sorry, [it is possible to embed images in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220884/html-can-images-be-displayed-without-hosting-online).

Comment: Hi thanks for reply,  So "/images/pic1" wont work in scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the images having a long cache life, and bootstrapped by first being online, you may be able to get away with your first solution, where you reference third-party URLs. But that is not likely the case, unless you have a very reliable third-party provider, and can rely on initial online use.

Most likely it will be a bit more involved...

If the images are static (or static copies are sufficient), then to run offline you would need to save the images as static assets served along with your application, or as inline [base64 encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images) images if they are small enough and you prefer not to serve additional files. This sort of thing is the only way to get a 100% offline app that you could e.g. bundle into a strictly offline mobile app.

If the images are dynamic in nature, it will be even more involved. In that case, you will need to synchronize them with some server side logic that you maintain. You could set your server to cache the images for a long time in order to satisfy offline clients, or use browser storage to cache them explicitly. This approach would still only work if you can rely on an online initialization period.

Comment: im running on raspberry pi with no internet connection, so just after running images from a folder :) Aslo they are very small gifs in firefox in kiosk mode Thanks

Comment: Ok, so middle solution (static file assets or base64 encoded) should work for you. If you go with files over inline, you'd reference the images relative to your script's served path. If script is in a `src` directory and images in an `images` directory which is a peer, then you can use e.g. `../images/[image-name]` as your src values.

Comment: I have been testing on firefox in windows, im guessing windows will give a totally different result.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue. The `img` tag and basic JavaScript (~ES5) that you have quoted so far are old and well-supported tech. On the other hand if you introduce ES6 syntax or other more recent goodies, your mileage may vary.

Comment: <img src="../images/orb1.png" alt="slideshow" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" />
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var imgs = ["orb1.png", "orb2.png",  that dont work ?

Comment: You would need `var imgs = ["../images/orb1.png", "../images/orb2.png"...`. And you would need to make sure the images are actually located in / served from that location.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it, with all your input. Thanks.

I used base64, converted using this site http://picbase64.com/

Then replaced URLs with encoded code..

Many Thanks